# Equality of two expressions describing a filter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, filters

Let $U$, $W$ be boolean lattices with order $\sqsupseteq$, and $U \supseteq W$. The top element of $U$ is the same as the top element of $W$. The bottom element of $U$ is the same as the bottom element of $W$.

Let $f$ be a filter on $W$.

Are the following two expressions equal?

1. $\bigcup_{X \in f} \left\{ Y \in U \mid Y
     \sqsupseteq X \right\}$;
2. $\left\{ L \in U \mid \forall X \in W : (X
     \sqsupseteq L \Rightarrow X \in f) \right\}$.

Are they both filters on $U$?

Comment: What you you mean $Y\in U$ and $X\in U$?

Comment: @TomCruise: I don't understand your question. By $Y\in U$ I mean that $Y$ is an elemetn of the set $U$.

Comment: Ok but then you say $Y\supseteq X$...

Comment: @TomCruise: Yes, I was wrong. I will edit the question.

Comment: @TomCruise: No, I have edited the question, and now 2. means the filter(?) on the boolean lattice $U$ consisting of all elements $L\in U$ such that every $X$ majorating $L$ is an element of the filter $f$

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: It seems that $T$ does not witness that $V$ can't be in (2).

Comment: In expression 2, should $\forall X\in U$ perhaps have been $\forall X\in W$?  Any $X$ outside $W$ has no chance to be in $f$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thanks, it was my error. Now have been corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counterexample, using the corrected version of formula 2. Let $U$ be the Boolean algebra of subsets of a 2-element set, say $\{0,1\}$.  In this 4-element Boolean algebra, let $W$ be the 2-element subalgebra containing just $\varnothing$ and $\{0,1\}$.  Let $f$ be the unique proper filter in $W$; it consists of just $\{0,1\}$.  Then your expression 1 gives just $f$ itself.  But your expression 2 gives the family $\{\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$.  For example, it contains $\{0\}$ because the only element of $W$ above $\{0\}$ is $\{0,1\}$, which is in $f$.

So expressions 1 and 2 are not in general equal.  Expression 1 always gives a filter in $U$, but, as the example shows, expression 2 need not give a filter.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\{L\in U:(\exists X\in f)(X\sqsubseteq L)\}$

$B=\{L\in U:(\forall X\in U)(X\sqsupseteq  L\implies X\in f)\}$

I believe these two sets are equivalent, using the fact that filters are closed upwards.

Suppose $L\in B$. Then $L\in f$. So $L\in A$.

Suppose $L\in A$.  Suppose $X\in U$ with $X\sqsupseteq L$. There exists $X'\in f$ with $X'\sqsubseteq L$. So $L\in f$. So $X\in f$ thus $L\in B$

Now I will try to show they are filters...

Comment: $f$ is closed upwards in $W$, but that doesn't mean that it's necessarily closed upwards in $U$ unless there's something I'm missing...